# recover old partition that became Unallocated space after Windows Media tool Use windows 10

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, partition-recovery, recovery-partition

I needed to install windows 10 on my laptop that didn't have an OS, so I used my friend's external drive, I created a new partition on his laptop and used the "official" windows media tool to get a bootable partition (biggest mistake ever apparently), so it created the partition I installed windows 10, and everything was alright, except that I can not access the old partition on that external drive there is only the bootable partition, and the rest became unallocated space.

I tried using diskpart to rename the volume and maybe get the partition back with no luck.

I am a software engineer, but my knowledge of partition tables and hard/SSD drives is limited.

How can I get back the data that is now in the unallocated space?

testDisk is the only free tool I found, except that disk drill seems to find many files, and I am letting it complete its scan.

If it is possible to recover the partition without having to pay these specialized vendors (disk drill recoverit etc.), that would be great, but if these paid options (or another open to suggestions), I am willing to go that route.

Comment: Use `testdisk` to recover and restore the old partition table, albeit minute data loss may occur if the ~4GB of Windows install files overwrote any previous data _(if any data loss occurs, it's likely to be minute)_. Once done, search the drive for missing data with `testdisk` and/or `photorec`.

Comment: You *should have* used the media creation usb on your own system and never put the other drive in your friends system to begin with.  Sorry this happened dude.  Bummer.. @JW0914 advice is probably all you can do at this point.  TestDisk is one of the best tools in the business.  Good luck.

Comment: what partition type to use with testdisk Intel/PC ? for NTFS ?

Comment: @BobMaza Intel/PC